# Chromedriver/Selenium issue

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I am using pyCharm to create a script. For the script I need chrome driver but keep receiving this error when running the program. I have download chromedriver and selenium multiple times. I am very very new to programing so any comments or help is much appreciated. [The image below shows the code and the errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx9wp.png)

Comment: The error message says it all. You need to find where Selenium is, copy the location, and add it to PATH.

Comment: For the future: 1- Never put links to screenshots on Stackoverflow when you can copy-paste the error message. 2- Google the error message before posting the question. 3- Search stackoverview for a similar question before posting a new on

Answer (score 0):

The problem's about the PATH of chrome_driver, you have to test if it is in the PATH `Users/Aftaab/Downloads/chromedriver` or no!
I believe that the correct PATH it's :

```
C:/Users/Aftaab/Downloads/chromedriver + chromedriver.exe
```

try to find the correct PATH by yourself then passed it as a string in `webdriver.Chrome`